# Python debug of the logger

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I need to debug a very strange behaviour of python logger... it is possible to have a sort of "logger of logger", that reports loggings operations?

For example: "logger is writing", "logger settings changed", etc...

Comment: Please describe the "very strange behaviour" instead. Otherwise, yes, you could use a debugger and set breakpoints on the logging operations.

Comment: I want what I have asked in the question

Comment: you would be better just describing the problem its self, someone might have seen such an issue and know a simple fix, or it might help others understand better what your trying to achieve and be able to suggest an approach to it.

Comment: If you're adamant on this, then, as said: use a debugger; set breakpoints or traces in the `logging` functions you want to report.

Comment: I cannot debug the code: I need a logger's log.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get without using an actual debugger or changing the stdlib is using a [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#filter-objects) on either loggers or handlers. Be aware that filters only get called after the level has been checked. Code looks like this:

```
import logging

def log_logs(record):
    print('logger has received record')
    return True

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addFilter(log_logs)

logger.error('error')
logger.debug('debug') # no output because default level is warning and debug is below that
```